# How to Automate Azure Data Factory Pipeline ReRuns

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone let me know if its possible to automatical ReRun a failed Pipeline in ADF?

As you can see, it's possible to manually Rerun a failed Pipeline

[image]

I was wondering if it's possible to get ADF to ReRun automatically?

Comment: You can use rest api to get the pipline name which failed and then rerun that.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks for reaching out. I have never come across your suggestion before. Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Hey, can you confirm what is the freq and schedule at which you need to rerun the failed pipeline? does it need to be instantly when the pipeline fails?

Comment: Hi @Nandan, thanks for getting in touch. Yes it would need to be within 2 minutes of failure. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ask that the failed pipelines needs to rerun instantly, you can follow the below custom logic purpose :

1. At the end of the pipelines actual logic, add a copy activity that would generate a file in case if the pipeline has failed.

Refer to my blog w.r.t managing an activity at an end for failure: https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

for specific 2 min, you can initially add a 2 min wait activity and then copy activity.

2. Then have a blob trigger to the same pipeline which would get triggered based on file generated

Answer (score 0):

To Automate Azure Data Factory Pipeline ReRuns You can use Rest APIs

I created Pipeline with web activities to run the Rest API's

- First, we need to take one web API to get the authorizarion token.

```
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Apps_tenant_ID>/oauth2/token
Method: POST
Body: grant_type=client_credentials &client_id=<Apps_Client_ID>&resource=https://management.azure.com&client_secret=<Apps_Client_Secret>
Header :  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

[image]

- Take second web activity to get all failed pipelines.

```
URL: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01
Method: POST
Body: {
  "lastUpdatedAfter": "@{subtractFromTime(utcnow(),5,'Minute')}",
  "lastUpdatedBefore": "@{utcnow()}",
  "filters": [
    {
      "operand": "Status",
      "operator": "Equals",
      "values": [
        "Failed"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
**Note**: this body will take `lastUpdatedBefore` as current time and `lastUpdatedAfter` as 5 mins before current time.
Header : "Authorization: @concat('Bearer ',activity('Web1').output.access_token)"
```

[image]

- After this took for each activity to run all the failed pipelines.

[image]

- Inside Foreach i called create run Rest Api to run the particular pipeline.

```
URL: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/@{item().pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01
Method: POST
Body: {}
```

[image]

- Then have a Schedule trigger to the same pipeline which would get triggered for every 5 mins and check it any pipeline failed in last 5 mis and will rerun that pipeline.

Comment: Hi @PratikLad, thanks again for respond. TBH, I thought it would be much easier than your suggestion..... Is there no other way?

Comment: Hi, can someone think of any other way to rerun a failed pipeline?